# Array Storing User Input

Tags: arrays, string

I've yet to get the hang of arrays, as you can probably see. I'm trying to create one that will store 10 strings which the user input, although I doubt I've gone the right way about it. At the moment I'm getting the error 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at InputLoop.main(InputLoop.java:22)' Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputLoop
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String array[] = new String[10];
    int num =11, i =0;
    System.out.println ("Enter a word");
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
         while (scan.hasNextInt()) // while non-integers are present...
        {

            scan.next();           //...read and discard input, then prompt again
            System.out.println ("Bad input. Enter a word");

        }

        array[i] = scan.next();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do anything with arrays in Java, you have to remember that array indexing *starts at 0*.

So when you declare an array of size 10, you get a 10-element array starting at 0 or 0-9. The 10th of your array is actually at index 9.

so where you have `num = 11` should probably be `num = array.length`

Answer (score 0):

Num needs to be set to 10. You're looping 11 times. For an array of size n, the indexes go from 0 to n-1.

Answer (score 0):

here you are declaring the array of size 10 and initializing num with 11

```
String array[] = new String[10];
```

so array will have its index from 0 to 9 i.e total 10...

and your for loop will rotate from 0 to 10 i.e total 11...and it will cause arrayindexoutofbound

either make value of num=10 or make your arraysize 11..